# Changing timezone to IST

Tags: android

I am programmatically trying to set the timezone to [Indian Standard Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Standard_Time) (IST) in [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29), but nothing seems to work!

Here's the code snippet:

```
SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
//  TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT +5:30"));
//  TimeZOne.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(s.format(c.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than changing the *default* time zone (which you're doing after creating the `SimpleDateFormat`) you should just set the time zone of the `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
s.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
System.out.println(s.format(new Date()));
```

Comment: "It's not working" doesn't give us any information. What is the actual result, and what's the expected result?